# Execute command inside another command

Tags: terminal, tmux, tty, recording

I'm trying to record my tmux session.
I've got an alias `record-session` which executes command from ttygif `ttyrec ~/ttygif/files/last-session`. As far as I understand ttygif starts new terminal instance and starts recording it.
Normally I have to do

```
$ record-session
$ tmux a
# Do something with tmux here
# C-b D
$ exit #to finish recording
```

But I'd like make it a little bit more automatic becuase I don't like how it's recorded everytime when I type `tmux a`.
I want to make an alias which would start recording and then attach to tmux session.
I've tried:

- `record-session ; tmux a`
- `(record-session ; tmux a)`
- `record-session & tmux a`
- `record-session && tmux a`
- `record-session | tmux a`
- `(tmux a ; record-session)`

Each without success. Every one of these commands starts the recording right after I close the tmux or doesn't record it at all.

Any ideas what is the right way to do it?

Comment: How about letting `ttyrec` start `tmux`: `ttyrec -e "tmux a" logfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found a solution. It appears that ttygif allows You to use a starting command with flag -e
So it's enough to do

```
ttyrec file_name -e "tmux a"
```

Or in my case

```
record-session -e "tmux a -t my_session"
```

Comment: This is what @Fiximan wrote before in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one solutions here:

- Use [tmux-logging](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging) plugin.
- Use a `.bash_profile` to log the [output to a script](http://blog.matoski.com/articles/tmux-auto-logging-output/).
- If you want to use `record-session` you can always use [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) to setup the ENV and run the commands.

There are probably more ways to do it, but best way IMHO would be to use the plugin.